# Python: get reason(s) why SSL certificate marked as not trusted

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssl, pyopenssl

I have a list of IDN domains, part of them have trusted certificates and I can easily get information about this certificates with usage of OpenSSL:

```
cert = ssl.get_server_certificate((domain, 443))
x509 = OpenSSL.crypto.load_certificate(OpenSSL.crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, cert)
print(x509.get_issuer())
print(x509.get_subject().get_components())
```

Other part of domains marked as untrusted in browser and you can check the reason(s) why, using inbuilt browser tools, like this:

[image]

So, my question: is there any way to get such list of reasons with usage of OpenSSL? If not, maybe there are some other approach to do it?